# counting events where events are bunched if there is a small time gap

Tags: sql, hive, counting

I am trying to count how many 'Uses' occur in my data set using HIVE.

I have columns for individual user IDs, timestamps in unix epoch time, event names, and length of events in seconds in my data.

'Use' is considered anytime a user triggers an event. The problem is if a user triggers an event and then triggers another within five minutes, I am to count as the same 'Use'

I'm having a difficult time mentally figuring out how to account for the five minute window when counting. I don't seem to be able to make a bunch of 'create tables' in HIVE like I would messily do in SQL to avoid too many subqueries, as I get lost easily in those.

This seems like it would be a standard problem, is there a smart or obvious solution to handling items like these?

Thank You

Comment: It would help both you understand the problem (and others) if you provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Ordering data by time and splitting it by user would make the task simple. For each user, scan the events ordered by time, and remember the latest event's time. If this event's time is within the 5-min window, just update the "latest event" timestamp; if outside the window, count it as an event. Splitting the stream by user allows to count different users in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hive, you can use `lag()` to see if there is another record five minutes before a given record.  If there is not, then set a flag to 1 and count that:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*,
             lag(timestamp) over (partition by user order by timestamp) as prev_timestamp
      from t
     ) t
where prev_timestamp is null or
      (timestamp - prev_timestamp) > 5*60;
```

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem perfectly. I need to investigate this "partitioning" feature clearly.